# Are Magento layers joined together?

Tags: php, magento, layout, configuration

Hi I`m new to Magento and I have to learn it for future project. But I cant get it, how layer configuration files get joined. My hypotheses are:

- All layout files for each request get joined together in global configuration (of course after joining there is some kind a caching process)
- There is some kinda mystical process, in which some layout page files (which will be used) get included in global configuration (Maybe it can be told by module im requesting with URL, but i cant imagine how).

So which of these my hypotheses is correct? Or if none, then how are the layout configuration files chosen for inclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are joined and there is nothing mythical about this.

For further reference please read every magento (layout and theming) related article in

- http://alanstorm.com/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base

and it is also worth to purchase "No Frills Magento Layout" book by Alan Storm to guide you through your magento designlife

Comment: Thank you, this was how I hoped it will be. :)